# Paste formula as text into cell via openxlsx or googlesheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, openxlsx

I'm trying to upload and convert an Excel file to Google Sheets. However, the formula will not evaluate in Google Sheets without first interacting with the cell. For example, in the sample code below, merely adding a space inside the cell (via the Sheets web UI) after the formula will produce the desired output (which is "Hola" and "adios" in cells A2 and A3).

```
library(googledrive)
library(openxlsx)

df <- structure(list(english.to.spanish = c("=GOOGLETRANSLATE(\"hello\", \"en\", \"es\")", 
                                      "=GOOGLETRANSLATE(\"goodbye\", \"en\", \"es\")")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                  -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
df

  english.to.spanish                             
  <chr>                                          
1 "=GOOGLETRANSLATE(\"hello\", \"en\", \"es\")"  
2 "=GOOGLETRANSLATE(\"goodbye\", \"en\", \"es\")"

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "eng_to_span")

writeData(wb,sheet = "eng_to_span",
          x = df)

saveWorkbook(wb,  "eng_to_spanish.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)

progress.sheet <- drive_upload(media = "eng_to_spanish.xlsx", 
                              type = "spreadsheet")

browseURL(drive_link(as_id(progress.sheet$id)))
```

I need to do this across 100's of spreadsheets, so I'm looking for a programmatic/scripting solution.

Comment: Google Drive and Sheets expect that an uploaded & converted Excel file was saved in a calculated (& valid) state. If you can use the Sheets & Drive REST API directly, I believe flagging the values being set as `USER_ENTERED` is sufficient. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption Perhaps the `r-googlesheets` library will be more useful in your case, rather than working with an intermediate xlsx file.

Comment: Thanks tehowch. I've found googlesheets to be very slow, so that's why I did the intermediate xlsx file. But maybe I could combine the two methods.

Comment: Which version? The latest is https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4